# Get Facebook user's details and big profile picture in one call

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-core, facebook-c#-sdk

I can get in one call `/me` details including `picture`, `email`, `name`.
But URL returned is of an extremely small picture (50px*50px).

I know I can make additional call to get bigger image with something like:

```
.../me/picture?width=999
```

But is it possible to combine it with:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=id,relationship_status,picture,email,gender,first_name,last_name,significant_other
```

to receive all this information in **one** request-response instead of two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me?fields=id,relationship_status,picture.width(999),email,gender,first_name,last_name,significant_other
```

You can make nested requests by following this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#fieldexpansion

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm. (ugly syntax, but... what ever works `;)` )

Comment: Do you know how I can ask for specific width and height?

Comment: There are height and width elements for the photo element. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/

Comment: I have already found the way(again, horrible syntax) picture.width(999).height(789)